# Image Rotation, Line Symmetry

Tags: graphics, image-processing, import

I'd like to import an image,  superimpose it,  reduce the opacity of the overlaid image, and then use a manipulate to rotate the top image to illustrate rotational symmetry.

The image below is using image editing software, not *Mathematica*, but illustrates the effect I am after.

[image: example of the effect I am after]

There are many nice images on the net that could be used to illustrate this concept.  Can this be done using *Mathematica* and the image processing commands?

I tried importing an image file,  then used `Show` and `ImageRotate`

for example,

```
g1 = Import[ graphic....]
Show [ g1,  ImageRotate[g1, pi/4]]
```

but that wasn't at all what I was looking for...

I'd appreciate any suggestions for commands that could achieve this effect.

My goal would be to create several `Manipulate`s with various images to illustrate various orders of symmetry with image files  (I've already done this with line drawings).

Some related hopefully useful images:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

[image: example 3]

[image: example 4]

[image: example 5]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another approach using a background to prevent cropping of the rotated image when its aspect ratio is far from `1`:

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyNu2.png"]
```

[image: img]

```
im2 = SetAlphaChannel[im, ColorNegate[im]];
bg = ImageCompose[
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[{Lighter[Orange], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], "Image", ImageSize -> 600], im2];

Manipulate[
 Show[ImageCompose[bg, ImageRotate[im2, angle, {600, 600}]]], {angle, 
  0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: manipulate]

**Edit**

If you want smooth blending instead of a sharp alpha channel as I did in the first approach, you could do this:

```
crop = Rasterize[
   Graphics[{White, Disk[]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
   "Image", ImageSize -> 600, Background -> Black];

Manipulate[
 SetAlphaChannel[
  ImageCompose[bg, {ImageRotate[bg, angle, {600, 600}], .5}], 
  crop], {angle, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: man2]

Here, I added another cropping mask in the form of a disk to prevent the partially uncovered corners from showing.

Comment: Thank you,  that's fantastic and just what I needed.  I also appreciate the extra help with dealing with images that are not square.   I've already put this approach to use on a lesson I'm giving to a student tomorrow.   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this maybe:

```
image = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 200];

Manipulate[ImageCompose[image, {ImageRotate[image, a], 0.5}], {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   ImageCompose is what I needed.  Great answer,  I appreciate your input.